# Calling observable inside an error callback in Angular with RxJs

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have two observable calls relying on each other, this works fine, but once an error occurs in the response I need to call another observable which rolls the transaction back.

ZThat is my code:

```
return this.myService.createOrder()
    .pipe(
        concatMap((res: MyResponse) => this.addProduct(res.orderId, PRODUCT_ID))  
    ).subscribe({
          error: (error: any): void => // TODO: Call another observable here passing res.orderId to rollback transaction
    });
```

As you can see in the **TODO** my plan is to call another service when an error occurs with `res.orderId`, but I don't like having nested subscriptions.

Is it possible to do that without creating nested subscriptions???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Emilien has pointed out, `catchError` is your friend in this case.

`catchError` expects, as parameter, a function which itself expects an `error` as input and return an `Observable`.

So, the code could look like this

```
// define a variable to hold the orderId in case an error occurs
let orderId: any

return this.myService.createOrder().pipe(
  tap((res: MyResponse) => orderId = res.orderId),
  concatMap((res: MyResponse) => this.addProduct(res.orderId, PRODUCT_ID)), 
  catchError((error: any) => {
    // this.rollBack is the function that creates the Observable that rolls back the transaction - I assume that this Observable will need orderId and mybe the error to be constructed
    // catchError returns such Observable which will be executed if an error ouucrs
    return this.rollBack(orderId, error)
  })
).subscribe(console.log);
```

As you see, in this case there is only one subscription for the entire chain of Observables.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it will solve but could you try with [CathError](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/error_handling/catch) ?

```js
return this.myService.createOrder().pipe(
  concatMap((res: MyResponse) => this.addProduct(res.orderId, PRODUCT_ID)), 
  catchError((res: MyResponse) => {
    // Call here your observable with res
  })
).subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: Yes I have this, but at this point the observable is still `open` and I would rather not add another subscription to it. I think the best way is to catch the error with `catchError` and then pipe with `map` and there call the subscription...something like that...

Answer (score 0):

#### Catch and Release

If you still want the source observable to error out. You can catch the error, run your rollback observable, then once it completes, re-throw the error.

That might look like this:

```ts
this.myService.createOrder().pipe(
  concatMap((res: MyResponse) => this.addProduct(res.orderId, PRODUCT_ID).pipe(
    catchError(err => concat(
      this.rollBack(res.orderId),
      throwError(() => err)
    )
  )  
).subscribe(...);
```